# GTK themes not working?

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk

Anytime I change the GTK theme, only the color changes. The button at the top of the window(s) stays the same. I have installed the dependencies it told me to and this happens with any theme I try.

[example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOU1B.jpg)

[example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvddJ.jpg)

it won't let me post more than two links, but I have tried 6 themes and they are all the same

Thanks!